# How to get the users who reacted to a message?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a giveaway bot. The bot is supposed to take the users who reacted and randomly select one from that list, but I can't figure out how to get the users who reacted.

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_role('giveaway')
async def giveaway(ctx, wait, *, reward):
    end = int(wait)
    giveEmbed = discord.Embed(title='A giveaway has begun!', description='React to this message to enter the giveaway.', color=discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 107, 33))
    giveEmbed.add_field(name='Prize:', value=f'{reward}', inline=True)
    giveEmbed.add_field(name='Time:', value=f'{time} hour(s) after message sent.', inline=True)
    message = await ctx.send(embed=giveEmbed)
    reaction = await message.add_reaction('')
    time.sleep(5)
    #can't figure out how to get the users who reacted here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the message again to get the 'updated' reactions:

```py
fetched_message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
reactions = fetched_message.reactions

for reaction in reactions:
    if str(reaction) == '':
        # This if the list of the users that reacted with `` to the message
        users = await reaction.users().flatten()
```

And btw `time.sleep(5)` it's blocking your code, change it to `await asyncio.sleep(5)`

Reference:

- [TextChannel.fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)
- [Message.reactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reactions#discord.Message.reactions)